# HeIp me for litle thing Countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript. How to add minute to datadate in that html/javascript?

Example:

Datadate is 3,19--> Wednesday 7pm. I wanna make it 3,19,30--> Wednesday 7pm past half (7:30pm).

```js
function getRemaining(EVENTDAY, EVENTHOUR, now) {
    now = new Date();

    var dow = now.getDay();

    var hour = now.getHours() + now.getMinutes() / 60 + now.getSeconds() / 3600;


    var offset = EVENTDAY - dow;


    if (offset < 0 || (offset === 0 && EVENTHOUR < hour)) {

        offset += 7;
    }


    var eventDate = now.getDate() + offset;


    var eventTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), eventDate,
    EVENTHOUR, 0, 0);

    var millis = eventTime.getTime() - now.getTime();


    var seconds = Math.round(millis / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds %= 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;


    return days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m ";
}

function tick() {
    $.each($('.countdown'), function (i, v) {
        startdate = $(this).attr('datadate');
        startdate = startdate.split(',');
        $(this).html(getRemaining(startdate[0], startdate[1]));
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="countdown" datadate='6,19'></span>

<br>
<span class="countdown" datadate='2,19'></span>

<br>
<span class="countdown" datadate='3,19'></span>

<br>
<span class="countdown" datadate='3,20'></span>

<br>
```

### Hope you can help me.

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Comment: This is not Java. It's Javascript. They are two entirely different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the last parameter from the function `getRemaining(EVENTDAY, EVENTHOUR, now)` is always `null` ( or `undefined` ). I removed the parameter and made a function-scoped variable.

I also made some visual changes to the code. Here You go, this should work:

```js
function getRemaining(EVENTDAY, EVENTHOUR, EVENTMINUTE) {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = EVENTDAY - now.getDay();
    var hour = now.getHours() + now.getMinutes() / 60 + now.getSeconds() / 3600;
    
    if (offset < 0 || (offset === 0 && EVENTHOUR < hour)) {
        offset += 7;
    }

    var eventDate = now.getDate() + offset;
    var eventTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), eventDate, EVENTHOUR, EVENTMINUTE, 0);
    var millis = eventTime.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var seconds = Math.round(millis / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    seconds %= 60;
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 24;

    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;

    return days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m ";
}

function tick() {
    $.each($('.countdown'), function (i, v) {
        startdate = $(this).attr('datadate');
        startdate = startdate.split(',');
        $(this).html(getRemaining(startdate[0], startdate[1], startdate[2]));
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="countdown" datadate='6,5,8'></span>
<span class="countdown" datadate='3,10,30'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like  [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Then:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 12th 2015, 6:05:32 pm
```